# 'Opcache' fails to install in Docker

Tags: php, apache, docker, debian, opcache

I have setup the new Docker container with image "FROM php:7.3-apache-stretch" and trying to install 'Opcache' into it but fails.

**System:** Linux

**PHP Version:** 7.3.11

**Apache Version:** Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)

**DockerFile**

```
FROM php:7.3-apache-stretch

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update
RUN apt-get -y update --fix-missing && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get --no-install-recommends install -y apt-utils && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Install useful tools and install important libaries
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install nano vim wget dialog libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-0 && \
    apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install mysql-client zlib1g-dev libzip-dev libicu-dev && \
    apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install --fix-missing apt-file apt-utils build-essential git curl && \ 
    apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install --fix-missing libcurl3 libcurl3-dev zip openssl && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Other PHP7 Extensions

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_sqlite && \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli && \
    docker-php-ext-install curl && \
    docker-php-ext-install tokenizer && \
    docker-php-ext-install json && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip && \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl && \
    docker-php-ext-install mbstring && \
    docker-php-ext-install gettext

# Install Freetype 
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get --no-install-recommends install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

# Enable apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

# Cleanup
RUN rm -rf /usr/src/*
```

**List of Extensions available in system:**

```
root@24dd119aaa1f:/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731# ls -l
total 4968
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff  111872 Nov 11 16:22 curl.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff  453536 Nov 11 16:24 gd.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff   18616 Nov 11 16:23 gettext.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 1667064 Nov 11 16:22 intl.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff   50216 Nov 11 16:22 json.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 1795120 Nov 11 16:23 mbstring.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff  170520 Nov 11 16:22 mysqli.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff  531752 Oct 25 02:54 opcache.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff   37800 Nov 11 16:21 pdo_mysql.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff   40176 Nov 11 16:21 pdo_sqlite.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff   80296 Oct 25 02:54 sodium.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff   27224 Nov 11 16:22 tokenizer.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff   78976 Nov 11 16:22 zip.so
```

```
root@24dd119aaa1f:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d# ls -l
total 28
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 16 Nov 11 16:24 docker-php-ext-gd.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 21 Nov 11 16:23 docker-php-ext-gettext.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 18 Nov 11 16:22 docker-php-ext-intl.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 20 Nov 11 16:22 docker-php-ext-mysqli.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 23 Nov 11 16:21 docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 20 Oct 25 02:54 docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 17 Nov 11 16:22 docker-php-ext-zip.ini
```

**php.ini**

```
; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled
opcache.enable=1

; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled for the CLI version of PHP
opcache.enable_cli=1

; The OPcache shared memory storage size.
opcache.memory_consumption=128

; The amount of memory for interned strings in Mbytes.
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8

; The maximum number of keys (scripts) in the OPcache hash table.
; Only numbers between 200 and 1000000 are allowed.
opcache.max_accelerated_files=10000
```

**When Tried to Install Opcache:**

```
root@24dd119aaa1f:/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731# docker-php-ext-install opcache
tar (child): /usr/src/php.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

**Ensured xz-utils is installed:**

```
root@24dd119aaa1f:/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731# apt-get install xz-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
xz-utils is already the newest version (5.2.2-1.2+b1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Not sure where its going wrong ?  btw, I can't re-create a docker image as that would hamper the existing projects.

Answer (score 1):

Using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache-stretch
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) opcache
```

this way:

```
docker build --tag stackoverflow .
```

gives cli output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/src/php/ext/opcache/modules

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,--rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and the command:

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint="" stackoverflow /bin/sh
```

and next into CLI

```
php -m
```

gives info:

```
[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks @Jimmix for your inputs, but sorry to say, as I mentioned in question, I can't really re-create the image as such so I have to figure out the solution while its in current running situation.  BTW, what does "-j$(nproc)" means in command, and what does it help to achieve ?

Comment: @SandipT  Change `FROM php:7.3-apache-stretch` to `FROM <your-image-name>` to build docker image from the point you already have your image. By doing this you have your image with opcache and the one that you start from is not modified.

Comment: thanks.. @Jimmix , will give it a try.  I just worry, I should not lose all the work I have had done so far with Image and Containers.  I mean, I have had installed so many other modules and did so many changes in php / mysql configuration file etc.  Will update with findings once tried your suggestion...